# Dealing with NA values in a conditional statement using comparison operators

Tags: python

I use the following conditional statement to define *metric*:

```
metric = "FAIL" if ((self.Mean <= -20.0) & (self.area_ratio>= 0.8)) else "PASS"
```

Sometimes, *self.area_ratio* = "NA".

This of course gives me the error:  TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'.

How can I keep this conditional statement format to define *metric*, while supporting that self.area_ratio could equal "NA" or could equal an integer? If *self.area_ratio* = "NA", metric should equal "PASS".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need.  You'll throw an exception if `self.area_ratio` isn't a number.  So you just catch that exception and set `metric` to `PASS` when you do.

```
try:
    metric = "FAIL" if (self.area_ratio >= 0.8) else "PASS"
except TypeError as ex:
    metric = "PASS"
```

If you want to do something different with other non-numeric values, then you can put more logic in the `except` clause to deal with distinguishing behavior between non-numeric values.

If you're sure that `NA` is the only non-numeric value you'll ever see, you can just add it to the conditional statement, as:

```
metric = "PASS" if self.area_ratio == 'NA' or (self.area_ratio < 0.8) else "FAIL"
```

but that's going to throw an exception you aren't dealing with if `self.area_ratio` is ever any other non-numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

It comes out easier if you use `or` instead of `and`.  `&` is for bit manipulation, so thats your main issue.

Assuming those are the only two values you will get (a float or the string "NA"), you can do this:

```
metric = "PASS" if self.area_ratio == "NA" or self.area_ratio >= 0.8 else "FAIL"
```

This isn't a super reliable way, but since you are already mixing types in the same variable...

Answer (score 0):

```
 metric = "PASS" if isinstance(self.area_ratio, str) else ("FAIL" if ((self.area_ratio != "NA") & (self.area_ratio>= 0.8)) else "PASS")
```

would also work as long as every string passes, but I wouldn't recommend doing it in one line.